# time complexity after sorting and using binary search

Tags: c, time, time-complexity

what will the time complexity be if I merge sort an array and apply a binary search function on it ? will it be `O(log n)`?

because

```
o(log n) + o(n log n) = O(log n)
```

Comment: Soerting is O(NlogN); you won't be able to reduce the time below that.  And O(logN) + O(NlogN) = O(NlogN), not O(logN).

Comment: Is `n*x`, where `n` is an awfully large positive number and `x` is some positive number, larger than `x` by itself? Now, is `n*x + x` closer to `n*x` or  `x`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you have any idea or hints at how you can search for an element with a time complexity of O(log n)

Comment: If you start with sorted data and maintain it as data is added and removed, then you won't have to perform a sort before searching.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons i have an UNSORTED array and i want to find an element in the array with a time complexity of O(log n)

Comment: The searching part using O(logN) is done using `bsearch()` or equivalent.  The penalty is that at some point, you have to sort the data so that you can use `bsearch()`.  I'm not aware of any O(logN) method for unsorted data.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the time complexity for Merge Sort, in the average case, is O(n log n). The one for Binary Search is O(log n).

Adding both methods, you have a complexity of O(n log n) instead of the one you said. Imagine that you are adding 1(log n) + n(log n), which is n+1(log n) --> (n log n).